# read.csv converts numeric to character/factor when values have too many significant digits

Tags: r, read.csv

**UPDATE**

When reading a csv with `read.csv`, I require numeric columns with `NA`, `""`, `NaN`, and `NULL` to be read into a `data.frame` as numeric. The problem is that some of these cases are converted to character.  In addition, I need to remove any row that does not have complete cases.
Example data set:

```
df1 <- read.csv(text="
+ cat ,vala , valb, valc, vald, vale
+ only_valid_row, 1, 1.00000000000002e3, 1.99999999999999999e-2, 2e3, 3
+ a   , ''  , 12  , 13  , 2.1 , 10
+ b   , 2e-3, NA  , 1.1 , 1.11, 8
+ c   , 3e2 , 2.1 , NaN , 3   , 7.1
+ d   , 2   , 1e2 , 0.3 ,     , 0.1
+ e   , 3   , 1e2 , 3.14, 6   , NULL
+ ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,na.strings=c('NA','NaN','NULL'),quote='\'',strip.white=TRUE)

sapply(df1,class)
        cat        vala        valb        valc        vald        vale 
#"character"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character"   "numeric"   "numeric" 
(df2 <- df1[complete.cases(df1),])
             cat vala valb                   valc vald vale
#1 only_valid_row    1 1000 1.99999999999999999e-2 2000    3
sapply(df2,class)
#        cat        vala        valb        valc        vald        vale 
#"character"   "numeric"   "numeric" "character"   "numeric"   "numeric"
```

Thanks for the previous answers, but it seems the root of the problem is the number of significant digits after the the decimal point (see `valc` above). Any suggestions?

Comment: adding `quote = '\'', na.strings = c('NA','NaN','NULL'), strip.white = TRUE` to your list in read.csv work?

Comment: @rawr please see the update:  it seems the real root of the problem I was having was that the numeric input had a large number of significant digits which is also converted to character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution similar to your.  Assuming only the first column are characters and the remaining columns are numbers which you are trying to convert.  I converted all of the columns to numeric values which forced the "", NaN and Nulls to NA which is easily removed with the complete.cases function:

```
df1 <- read.csv(text="
cat ,vala , valb, valc, vald, vale
                only_valid_row, 1, 1e3, 2, 2e3, 3
                a   , ''  , 12  , 13  , 2.1 , 10
                b   , 2e-3, NA  , 1.1 , 1.11, 8
                c   , 3e2 , 2.1 , NaN , 3   , 7.1
                d   , 2   , 1e2 , 0.3 ,     , 0.1
                e   , 3   , 1e2 , 3.14, 6   , NULL
                ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#convert to numeruic and construct new dataframe
converted<-apply(df1[,-1], 2, function(x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})
newdf<-data.frame(df1[1], converted)
#return complete cases
newdf<-newdf[complete.cases(newdf),]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer, but I updated the question after finding the root of the problem wasn't the null or empty fields, it was the length of the numeric input.

Comment: Ok, but even with your revised data, the above code should still work, if you don't mind the slight floating point rounding.

Comment: At least one problem i see:  any column could be a character column or a numeric column. No specific order.